# Firing an Insert trigger only when there is no data in the target table similar to the data from the inserted

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I am trying to execute a SQL Insert trigger which is fired and inserts some data into another table when data is inserted into a table which is a straight forward trigger but I am trying to check a condition before firing the trigger which is to find if the data similar to the inserted data is already in the target table. I tried with the following query

```
CREATE trigger [dbo].[trgI_InsertINTOLastTrade]
ON [dbo].[tblCC]
AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

   IF(SELECT COUNT(id) AS IDC 
      FROM LastTrades 
      WHERE product = inserted.Product 
        AND grade = inserted.grade 
        AND Term = inserted.Term 
        AND ISNULL(Pipeline, '') = inserted.Pipeline 
        AND ISNULL([Index], '') = inserted.[Index]) != 0
   BEGIN
       RETURN
   END

   INSERT INTO LastTrades(Product, Grade, Term, Pipeline,[Index], LastTradeValue)
       SELECT 
           Product, Grade, Term, Pipeline, [Index], LastTradeValue 
       FROM
           inserted 
END
```

When I execute the above query I get these errors:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trgI_InsertINTOLastTrade, Line 15
>   The multi-part identifier "inserted.Product" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trgI_InsertINTOLastTrade, Line 15
>   The multi-part identifier "inserted.grade" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trgI_InsertINTOLastTrade, Line 15
>   The multi-part identifier "inserted.Term" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trgI_InsertINTOLastTrade, Line 15
>   The multi-part identifier "inserted.Pipeline" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trgI_InsertINTOLastTrade, Line 15
>   The multi-part identifier "inserted.Index" could not be bound.

Is there any good way I can solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Before you call inserted.Product, you need to declare it in "from" statement.

```
CREATE trigger [dbo].[trgI_InsertINTOLastTrade]
on [dbo].[tblCC]
after insert
as
begin
SET NOCOUNT ON

IF(
    select  count(id) AS IDC 
    from    LastTrades 
                inner join inserted i
                on  product=i.Product 
                    and grade=i.grade 
                    and Term=i.Term 
                    and ISNULL(Pipeline,'')=i.Pipeline 
                    and ISNULL([Index],'')=i.[Index]) !=0
Begin
Return
End
insert into LastTrades(Product,Grade,Term,Pipeline,[Index],LastTradeValue)
Select Product,Grade,Term,Pipeline,[Index],LastTradeValue from inserted 

end
```

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you only want to insert rows that don't yet exist in the other table. The way you have coded it will insert all rows from your insert even if a given row already exists in the second table. This is because sql servers triggers fire once per operation. You need to code your triggers to handle this. Something like this should be close.

```
CREATE trigger [dbo].[trgI_InsertINTOLastTrade] on [dbo].[tblCC] after insert as 
begin

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    insert into LastTrades(Product,Grade,Term,Pipeline,[Index],LastTradeValue)
    Select i.Product
        , i.Grade
        , i.Term
        , i.Pipeline
        , i.[Index]
        , i.LastTradeValue 
    from inserted i
    left join LastTrades lt on lt.product = inserted.Product 
            and lt.grade = inserted.grade 
            and lt.Term = inserted.Term 
            and ISNULL(lt.Pipeline, '') = inserted.Pipeline 
            and ISNULL([Index], '') = inserted.[Index]
    where lt.Product is not null

end
```